# Entity Framework Too slow /Memory leak

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework

I'm doing a Lot of Work With EntityFramework, like millions Inserts and Updates.
However, by time it Get Slower and Slower...

I tried usign some ways to improve performance. Like:

```
db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
```

tried too:

```
db.Table.AsNoTracking();
```

When i change all this things it really gets Faster. However Memory used start to increases and until it give me exception.

Has anyone had this situation?
Thanks

Comment: Are you keeping a single instance of your `DbContext` derived type alive over lots of operations?

Comment: Yes One instance..I tried too Reloading the    DbContext and Diposing..

Comment: You should generally be using a single context per "operation." Such as fetching user details, facilitating a logon, etc. Is there a reason you keep a single context?

Comment: i tried to dispose, and them re-create it. but it still give me out of memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For millions insert and Update, Everything give out of memory, i've tried all..
Only worked for me when i stop use the context and use **ADO** or Another Micro ORM like **Dapper**.

Answer (score 2):

The `DbContext` stores all the entities you have fetched or added to a `DbSet`. As others have suggested, you need to dispose of the context after each group of operations (a set of closely-related operations - e.g. a web request) and create a new one.

In the case of inserting millions of entities, that might mean creating a new context every 1,000 entities for example. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework) gives you all you need to know about inserting thousands of entities.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried do use Dispose() and then create a new one as you suggest.Almost ever record But it Still give the exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing only insertion and updates - try to use db.Database.SqlQuery(queryString, object).

Entity framework keeps in memory all attached objects. So having millions of them may cause a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended offers a clean interface for doing faster bulk updates, and deletes. I think it only works with SQL Server, but it may give you a quick solution to your performance issue.

Updates can be done like this:

```
context.Users.Where(u => u.FirstName == "Firstname").Delete();
```

Deletes can be done in a similar fashion:

```
context.Tasks.Where(t => t.StatusId == 1).Update(t => new Task { StatusId = 2 });
```

Comment: This doesn't help insert or update values - it can only update from a query.

Comment: The idea is that updating with a query is much faster than loading, changing, persisting

Comment: Inserting is already done in one command if you use the same context